# Preconditioners for $Ax=y$ that rely on hierarchical statistical modeling

Tags: linear-algebra, st.statistics, na.numerical-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

Solving $Ax=y$ exactly can be done as:

- fit a linear autoregressive model by treating rows of $A$ as data
- apply this model to $A^T y$

Imperfect predictive model corresponds to an approximate inverse of $A$. Could be used as a preconditioner to solve $Ax=y$ iteratively.

In high-dimensional setting, a hierarchical predictive model would be tractable. **Has anything like this been done?** Any literature pointers appreciated!

---

Background: Eq. 5.6 of Pourahmadi, High-Dimensional Covariance Estimation gives the following representation:

$$(A^T A)^{-1}=D^{-1}(I-B)$$

- $B_{ij}$ is a coefficient of autoregressive linear model, contribution of $x_j$ to $x_i$, $i\ne j$
- $D$ is a diagonal matrix of squared residuals observed when applying this model to rows of $A$.

We can use $f(z)$ to indicate application of this predictive model to $z$, and $r_A(f)$ the diagonal matrix of squared residuals of $f$ evaluated on $A$.

$$(A^T A)^{-1} z = r_A(f)^{-1}(z - f(z))$$

For full-rank $A$, and $z=A^{T} y$, can write the solution of $Ax=y$ as follows

$$A^\dagger y=(A^T A)^{-1} A^T y = r_A(f)^{-1}(z - f(z))$$

Using an approximate $r_A$ and $f$, the equality no longer holds, but may correspond to a convergent iterative method.

- [correctness checks (Python)](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1tXmS6kZcJ8hsfvzKaZSCvXf7iNRT25UG),
- [correctness checks (Mathematica)](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/whitening_inverse_transposed.nb)